# flvtool2 batch process in SSH command?

Tags: flv, streaming-flv-video, pseudo-streaming

I want to perform hundreds of video in our server to execute command like this one

flvtool2 -U video.flv

but the problem is I can't find any command to perform batch process.

is there a way to perform batch process?

thanks, TIA

also question can this be done in PHP execute command? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, with this command in ssh

ls -1 *.flv | while read file; do cat "$file" | flvtool2 -U stdin "$file" ; done

thanks to this link
http://michaelangela.wordpress.com/2008/06/30/how-to-add-duration-info-to-a-flv-file-with-the-flvtool2-command/

if you need this kind of command try it, it works on me :)